# LL(1) grammar for conditional statements

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I'm creating a parser for Pascal and I'm stuck at conditional statements.

Suppose I have this code snippet:

```
if ((10 mod 3) = 1) then ...
```

This is valid pascal if statement. However when I try to come up with LL(1) grammar for the `((10 mod 3) = 1)` expression I crash and burn on the parentheses. Problem is, that the condition above can be rewritten as `if (10 mod 3) = 1 then ...` or thanks to operator precedence as `if 10 mod 3 = 1 then ...`

I have typical LL(1) grammar for arithmetic expressions:

```
E  -> TE'
E' -> ADD_SUB TE' | epsion
T  -> FT'
T' -> MUL_DIV FT' | epsilon
F  -> 'number' | '(' E ')'

ADD_SUB -> '+' | '-'
MUL_DIV -> '*' | 'div' | 'mod'
```

However I can't come up with LL(1) grammar for the whole condition. I thought of something like:

```
CE  -> CT CE'
CE' -> 'or' CT CE' | epsion
CT  -> CF CT'
CT' -> 'and' CF CT' | epsilon
CF  -> E REL-OP E | '(' E REL-OP E ')' | 'not' E REL-OP E

REL-OP -> '=' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '<>
```

Where `E` is `E` from the arithmetic expression grammar above.

This isn't LL(1), because the `CF -> E REL_OP E` and `CF -> '(' E REL-OP E ')'` rules contain first-first collision of `'('`.

Any ideas how to fix the first-first collision?

Comment: @MitchWheat project for "Programming languages and compilers" class :)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, a Pascal expression can include comparison operators and boolean operators, since it has a boolean type. So boolean expressions can appear anywhere an expression can appear, and not just in `if` statements.

So you need to extend `expression` (or `E`, as you write it) in such a way that `(10 mod 3) = 1` is an `expression` (and consequently `((10 mod 3) = 1)` is an `expression`), and then an `if` statement starts with `"if" expression "then"`.

If you really want to create a separate syntactic category for `conditional expression` (`CE`), then you have to go all the way down to the bottom of the precedence hierarchy, so that you would end up with a list which starts with something like

```
CE  -> CT CE'
CE' -> "or" CT CE' | epsilon
```

and ends with

```
CF  -> 'number' | '(' CE ')'
```

The last of those productions would be simple duplicates of the existing expression grammar, with a consistent change to non-terminal names. But that's a lot of unnecessary duplication.